# Is it possible to export a chart in a SSRS Report to PDF?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a Report with Tables and Charts. Is it possible to make the charts invisible and **add a link** (Exporting Table as a Chart in PDF) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the chart in another report and then add a link in the first report that exports the seconds report. You can add parameters to this call if required.

http://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=PDF

For more info on creating the link in the correct format check here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference?view=sql-server-ver15

Alternatively you could have both table and chart in 1 report. Have a parameter that determines what 'mode' its in and hide the chart or table respectively, default this parameter to hide the chart. Your link would then call the same report via a URL but with the `mode` parameter set to show the chart.

Comment: Great job. Here is also a great link for passing parameter with link. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered your question please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the vote up/down buttons on the left). This helps other SO users find answers to similar questions in the future.